# Realm not syncing with MongoDB Atlas after I clear app data

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, react-native, realm

I am developing an app with React Native and I am using MongoDB with Realm.
When I create a User for the first time the RealmProvider works fine and I can save and fetch data from Realm using `useObject()` and `useQuery()`, but the moment I clear app data from settings these two hooks return empty objects even though data is saved in MongoDB Atlas.

This is Realm config code:

```
export const getRealmConfig = (app: App) => {

const behaviorConfiguration: Realm.OpenRealmBehaviorConfiguration = {
    type: "openImmediately",
};

const REALM_CONFIG: Realm.Configuration = {
    schema: [
        Profile, 
        User,
        MessageProfile, 
        Article, 
        Post, 
        Feed, 
        Blog
    ],
    schemaVersion: 5,
    sync: {
        flexible: true,
        user: app.currentUser!,
        newRealmFileBehavior: behaviorConfiguration,
        existingRealmFileBehavior: behaviorConfiguration,
        onError: console.error
    }
};

return REALM_CONFIG
}
```

This is `RealmProvider` component:

```
 <AppProvider id={app_id}>
     <UserProvider fallback={<Login/>}>
         <RealmProvider {...getRealmConfig(app)}>
              .....
         </RealmProvider>
     </UserProvider>
</AppProvider>
```

P.S `app.currentUser.isLoggedin` returns `true` what means there should be a user, but `app.currentUser` returns an empty object.

Comment: The question is unclear. In one context it states that after 'clearing app data from settings' you can no longer read data, which if the data was cleared, would make sense as there would be no data to read. But the question also mentions `currentUser` which does not appear to be related to the other part of the question... or is it? Can you clarify what's being asked and please limit posts to one question with one issue; multiple questions/issues should be separated.

Comment: If there is no data locally it should fetch data from the server if I am right, but this is not happening. That's the issue.

Comment: You are correct - but some additional troubleshooting is needed. For example, if your Realm contains 10 people objects, and those are deleted, it also deletes them off the server - that's how sync works; it keeps the client and server synchronized. Is that the case or are you doing something else to *clear app data from settings*?. Also, log into the Realm console and check the Sync error log. Are there any errors? If so, what are they?

Comment: The objects have not been deleted on the server they're only deleted locally on my device. I do not see any errors on the Logs.

Comment: Again - if you delete the objects locally, that action is sync'd to the server and the objects are deleted from the server as well. That's the whole idea of Sync - it keeps the data on the device 'the same as' aka sync'd, to the server. The key here is that if objects are deleted on the device and those changes are *not* reflected on the server, then the Sync function is not set up or working correctly. Ensure your app is observing the objects then manually add an object in Realm console and see if the App reacts. If not, it's not syncing.

Comment: Yes I understand. I haven't deleted objects with code, I just cleared the app data and cache, and now there is no object retrieved even though the objects are still on the server.

Comment: Thanks - did you perform the test I outlined? What was the result?

Comment: Adding objects manually does not reflect the App.

Comment: Well, then your sync'ing is not set up correctly. It could be a setting within the Realm console or that the sync engine has stopped..  or it could be something in your code but I don't think we can help much further here since the issue lies outside of the code in the question. Wish we could do more

Comment: When you clear app data from settings, it affects the local state and storage of your application. It also affects the ability to interact with MongoDB Realm and synchronize data.